# Amazon S3 :: redirect on noSuchKeyError

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to refirect on another object on S3 when noSuchKeyError (object not found).
How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have provided very little information so I don't know if this advise is useful or not.  However, if you configure your S3 bucket for website hosting, it is possible to define custom error pages that map to particular HTTP error codes, as explained [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CustomErrorDocSupport.html).